# Unable to set text in android webview using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a webview with following settings :

```
mView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
mView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
mView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

After loading a webpage, when I try to execute Javascript:

```
mView.loadUrl("javascript:document.querySelector('input[type=password]').value ='" + password + "'");
```

It **opens a new tab** or window **instead of setting the value of password field**.

Output of `document.querySelector('input[type=password]')`  (from console) :

`<input type="password" name="userpassword" id="userpassword" maxlength="6" style="width: 128px; height: 18px">`

I tried executing the same javascript from console. It works!

I have also configured webviewclient:

```
mView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.d(TAG, " shouldOverrideUrlLoading :" + url);
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                Log.d(TAG, "onPageStarted " + url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                        String description, String failingUrl) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + description);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Android Kitkat (4.4, API level 19), you can use [`evaluateJavascript`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)).

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    webView.evaluateJavascript("js_code", null);
} else {
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:js_code");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`loadUrl` method, loads the provided URL in the WebView. What you have to do is execute the `evaluateJavascript` method.

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("document.querySelector('input[type=password]').value ='" + password + "'", new ValueCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
        /// This callback is called after a result is returned by the script.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting quotes on your CSS selector.

It should be:

```
document.querySelector('input[type="password"]');
```

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2vkyu2ce/)